# Checking value of "type" attribute of input field

Tags: jquery, testcase

I am making test cases for automation testing. I want to check whether the password fields in my form have `type="password"` (for `input` elements) or not...

How can I do this using jquery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next command will give you the type of an an element with an ID of `inputId`:

```
$("#inputId").attr('type');
```

Then you can simply check anything you want about it's type.

Answer (score 1):

`$(selector).is(":password")` will give you `true` 
`$(selector).attr("type")` will give you `password`

Click to see a [demo](http://jsbin.com/ivikux/2/edit#preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use :password selector and see if it returns anything

```
if($(':password').length) {
  Do something if exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check with `if` and `.length`

`if($("#haspassword input[type='password']").length > 0)`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xU3se/

The above example checks a specific form with `#haspassword`. If the `length` is bigger than zero then do something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `:password` pseudo class?

Answer (score -1):

```
$type = $("#idOfYourPassField").attr("type");

if($type==='password')
//its a password
```

Comment: There are better ways to achieve this, most certainly with jQuery